# How to combine different AWS glue catalog table to get metadata information of many tables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have many AWS Glue catalog table that contains metadata information about s3 files. I have created catalog table using glue crawler.

The problem here is - I have many s3 locations (let's say many upstream files). When I crawl the different s3 locations different data catalog tables are getting generated. Let's say, if I have 10 different s3 location with diff schema, 10 diff. catalog tables are generated.

I am looking to get all the tables (10 tables) metadata info in 1 table so that i can get s3 locations, column names, table names, record count, data type in one go. I am planning to create quicksight visualization to present these metadata info of all 10 files.

Is there any way to achieve this? Sorry if it's too basic question as I am new to aws world

Answer (score -1):

@BigD i don't think this is possible today. The crawler generates a new table for each data source. Even i would like AWS Glue to put all of them into a single 'table', however, i think the current functionality is to create separate tables only.